# How rare are Foresaken Masters and where do they appear?

Tags: path-of-exile

Just recently, the Forsaken Masters expansion for Path of Exile was released and I want to know whether I was on a lucky Streak... Or if the masters are common... Or that they're rare and I'll not be seeing any anytime soon.

So, my question is:
**What is the rate of spawning for the masters? and:**

1. Does being lower level than the area you're in affect the rate they appear,
2. Does being in a party increase/decrease appearance rates and
3. Where do they appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Probably not. The masters seem to be a part of the map and the map itself doesn't seem to be affected by the level or amount of players.
2. Again, probably not, with the same reason.
3. **In normal difficulty the masters only appear in certain areas and only two of them are in each act. See [this](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Masters) link and take a look at the specific sites of the masters. After normal difficulty any master can spawn in any map.**

**Edit:** I just downloaded the newest patch and the patch notes state that "The spawn chance of Masters has been reduced in The Fetid Pool, The Flooded Depths, The Ship Graveyard Cave and The Tidal Island." This means that the chance of a master spawning is indeed linked to the map. It also means that the spawn rate differs from map to map.

**Edit:** Note that the wiki I linked isn't always 100% up to date because POE is being patched every other day. Anyway, what I want to say is that the masters actually appear in more maps than the wiki claims. For example, if I recall it correctly, I found Elreon in "The Cavern of Wrath" (in Act 1 normal difficulty) where only Haku should be.

**Edit:** Deleted some statements and assumptions that weren't useful anymore.

Comment: I rolled from lower submerged passage, with Eleron to upper submerged passage, and was staring at Eleron again, so he was in back to back maps, both were definitely open at the same time.

Comment: THanks for the answer, and yeah... It seems like your explaination matches the evidence I had... (I made 20 instances of the same area in two areas and only one out of the 40 I made had a master in it).  
Also, there's a way to forcibally close instances. Just forcibilly disconnect (ie. Disconnection from Steam, Requests timing out etc.). You'll lose progress when it happens, but you can save progress by teleporting to a new area or back to down before disconnecting.

Comment: @Kexlox Yeah, I can confirm that. If the number of instances really does matters somehow (which seems very unlikely at the moment) the effect is limited to the map which has those instances. Another map - another situation.